# How to get Firesbase firestore document in the same sequence I have stored it using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

I have created a collection and storing some data to Firease Firestore. When I am retrieving those data it is sorted as per document id alphabetically. But I want to retrieve and sort it in the same sequence I have created and stored the documents.

I have tried to do so by adding a timestamp in each documents and generating the list by using orderBy('fieldName') but it is not working.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('products')
  //Admin id have to place in User App
      .where('documentType', isEqualTo: subject)
      .where('standard', isEqualTo: standard)
      .where('publisherId', isEqualTo: widget.data['publisherId'])
      .orderBy('timestamp')
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Column(
        children: const [
          Text('Something went wrong'),
          SizedBox(
            height: 600,
          )
        ],
      );
    }
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Column(
        children: const [
          LinearProgressIndicator(color: Colors.lightGreen,backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,),
          SizedBox(
            height: 600,
          )
        ],
      );
    }
    if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
      return const LinearProgressIndicator(color: Colors.lightGreen,backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,);
    }
    final sortedDocs = snapshot.data!.docs;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: 600, // Set the desired minimum height here
        ),
        child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: sortedDocs.length,
            crossAxisCount: screenWidth<=900&&screenWidth>600?4:screenWidth<=1150&&screenWidth>900?5:screenWidth>1150?6:2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return DocumentDisplayModel(
                products: sortedDocs[index],
                count: screenWidth<=900&&screenWidth>600?4:screenWidth<=1150&&screenWidth>900?5:screenWidth>1150?6:2,
                publisherId: widget.data['publisherId'], userData: widget.data,);
            },
            staggeredTileBuilder: (context) => const StaggeredTile.fit(1)),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Do you actually add a `timestamp` field to your documents when you create them? Keep in mind that we can only see what you show us, so it really helps if you show the code writing a document - nor a screenshot of an existing document.